# JPA + Weblogic JNDI + row locks contention

Tags: hibernate, jpa, weblogic, locks

I have implemented JPA JNDI using Weblogic. For DB, Oracle is used.

System is not allowing more than one DML statements on same table within a transaction. Getting error as 'row locks contention' in oracle logs (AWR report).

In oracle forums, row lock error is considered as application bug. Can some one suggest how to fix this in JPA

```
<properties>
<property name="hibernate.dialect"
    value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource"
    value="xxxxxxxx" />
<property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
    value="org.hibernate.transaction.WeblogicTransactionManagerLookup" />
<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory.class"
    value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory" />
<property name="hibernate.hibernate.session_factory_name"
    value="session_factory" />
<property name="hibernate.jndi.class"
    value="weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory" />
<property name="hibernate.jndi.url"
    value="t3://xxxxxxxx:yyyy" />
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class"
    value="jta" />
<property name="hibernate.jta.UserTransaction"
    value="weblogic.transaction.UserTransaction" />
<property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode"
    value="after_statement" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit"
    value="true" />
```

Comment: Why are there dml statements?  Are you using DDL table generation?  If so, you'll need a non JTA datasource.

Comment: using two update query or one insert and one update on same table. I'm not using DDL statements

Comment: Show what you are doing.  What statements are locking?  Try making your transactions smaller so that row locks are not held as long and do not span as many overlapping rows/tables.

Comment: Check the persistence.xml file attached in the main section

Comment: even it is simple update still it is showing row locks in DB. what i suspect is application is not passing commit after every update. only when we close entitymanager commit is getting fired. however in the code we have commit after every update.